# FM Circuit Simulation

Tags: simulation, frequency-modulation

I tried to simulate a circuit that I found in google. I adjusted some of the values in the tank circuit but the output waveform resembles that of amplitude modulated wave. What could possibly be wrong with this FM Transmitter circuit?
[image: Simulation]

Comment: I’m guessing 100MHz is the carrier, what’s the message signal?

Comment: My bad, it's actually not the carrier. It's supposed to be the mic so it's supposed to be the message signal. Therefore it's frequency should be between 20-20, 000 Hz right?

Answer (score 1):

With the simple circuit you have, there is no explicit frequency control element like a varactor diode. The frequency is varied by varying the bias, and so the stray capacitance, of the transistor, through C5. If your simulator has got a sufficiently good transistor model, then you should be able to see this effect if you measure the frequency changes accurately.

As this bias changes, your circuit will produce both frequency changes and amplitude changes. For a hobbyist circuit, that FM will be quite sufficient to broadcast a signal to an ordinary FM receiver<sup>1</sup>. The receiver will ignore the amplitude changes.

In a professional circuit, amplitude would probably be stabilised by feedback, and frequency modulation done with a varactor.

For an educational circuit, it would probably be better to find a varactor controlled one to study and simulate, as the changing transistor strays are a second order, generally unwanted, effect, which may not be included in all transistor models. All real transistors have them though, and if you build this circuit, you will get some FM.

(1) Audioguru points out in comments that a commercial audio FM receiver will be expecting some pre-emphasis on the modulation. You would apply to the signal before it gets to your modulator, so it's not really in the scope of this question. Even if you fail to do this, tones and speech will be identifiable. Way back in college, I built a an FM transmitter using a ring-of-three oscillator built with a 7400 TTL NAND gate, varying the supply voltage to vary its oscillation frequency, receiving the 3rd harmonic on an ordinary FM receiver. No pre-emphasis, but speech was perfectly intelligible, when used as a bug in neighbours' rooms!

Comment: All FM radio stations produce pre-emphasis (treble boost) and all FM radios produce matched de-emphasis (treble cut). Then this very simple FM transmitter will sound muffled (no high audio frequencies) on any FM radio.